# Is there a name for a comic relief character that temporarily becomes highly capable?

Tags: character-analysis, terminology, tropes

This is a trope that I've seen sometimes in comic books. I haven't seen it in prose fiction yet.

Sometimes, we see a character who provides comic relief become highly capable for a single issue or chapter. Examples include a few Donald Duck stories, or Lambik from Suske & Wiske (Spike and Suzy).

This phenomenon usually happens when the story requires a strong character to get something done; the character who provides comic relief is a logical choice as they can afford to be somewhat inconsistent.

Is there a name for this trope?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most related trope would probably be [Crouching Moron, Hidden Badass](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrouchingMoronHiddenBadass), when a minor character with no apparent skills turns out to be a super-secret ninja-assasin in disguise.

A subtrope of this is [Took a Level in Badass](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TookALevelInBadass), which is seems to be pretty much what you're looking for. This is when a character pretty much suddenly develops a cool power, though it can be temporary or permanent.

Also could be [Beware the Silly Ones](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BewareTheSillyOnes), where a goofy villain turns out to be your worst nightmare. The [Undertale](http://undertale.com/) genocide route [boss](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Sans) is a good example of this. [Beware the Nice Ones](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BewareTheNiceOnes) and [Beware the Quiet Ones](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BewareTheQuietOnes) are also similar.

Warning: All but 2 links are TV tropes links. [Click at your own risk...](https://xkcd.com/609/)